# Parse.com PFQuery & Cache crash my app

Tags: parse-platform, ios9, pfquery

Hello everyone I am using parse.com In my app .

To get SOME data and run a PFQuery In research I added also

> [userQuery setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];

So far so good , but when you run the ' application crash and do not understand why ... If I remove the search function of the cache in the app does not crash .

Someone can ' help me understand a thing happens ?

This is my query

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];

            [userQuery whereKey:kUNIUserLastNameKey equalTo:[currentUser objectForKey:kUNIUserLastNameKey]];

            [userQuery setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];

            [userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                if (!error) {

                NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    [nameArray addObject:object];

                    NSString *welcome = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"welcome %@!", [object objectForKey:kUNIUserLastNameKey]];


                }
            }
        }];
```

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when you crash?  Is anything printed in the debug console as it crashes?

Comment: no debugging does not write anything I returned only a breakpoint on the line query.cachePolicy ( I enabled all exceptions breakpoint to understand where crashes )